# iPhone message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have a weird problem which causing crash, when I touch textfield quickly when my UITableviewContrller shows up.
  It doesn't not always happen. maybe about 2 crashes of 10 tests.
  It works fine previously, but I don't know why it sometimes crash now.

iPhone4 on iOS7.1.
    crash message.  It crash in OrderTableViewController. Before crash, I check that the retainCount is 1, so I don't know how this happen. I have no idea why it's deallocated.

```
2014-04-01 09:35:57.628 [17027:60b] *** -[OrderTableViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17fef520
```

Here's my code for pushing viewController.
   I believe it's correct. I use it all the time.

```
OrderTableViewController *orderViewController = [[OrderTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OrderTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    orderViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

    [self pushViewController:orderViewController animated:YES];
    [orderViewController release];
```

I don't declare textfield as retain. I'm not sure if it's the problem.
    UITextField *uname;
    UITextField *utel;

```
uname = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 8, 120, 30)];
uname.BorderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
uname.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad;
uname.delegate=self;


utel = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180-40, 8, 120+40, 30)];
utel.BorderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
utel.delegate=self;
utel.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

- (void)dealloc {
[uname release];uname=nil;
[utel release];utel =nil;
[super dealloc];
}
```

I tried profile by instrument with zombie template, but I can't find something useful.
   Here're questions.
   1. Any ideas for this issues?
   2. How to workaround this kind of issues. I tried remove the code of [orderViewController release];  and retainCount become 2, it seems OK for 20 tests. But, it causes memory leak. how to reduced this leak issues. Could I release it in the navigation controller, when I don't need it? I know it's more complicated, but I don't know better way to workaround.
  Form message of crash , it seems related to OrderViewController over-release, but I can't find the problem. Is there other problem causing the error message?
 Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just to verify, you are not using arc, correct?

Comment: No , I'm not using arc.

Comment: Can I enquirer why your not using ARC??? You do know apps submitted to the app store must use ARC???

Comment: @Popeye the app store doesn't care if you use ARC or not. (Though I agree, nearly everybody ought to be using it)

Comment: @jrturton yes you are totally correct I was thinking of this line `"Important: Xcode 5.1 no longer supports building OS X apps that use garbage collection; attempting to build such targets results in a build error. You should employ the Xcode migration tool to convert to ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) on all projects using garbage collection. For more information about transitioning to ARC, see Transitioning to ARC Release Notes."` from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_1.html

Comment: I just couldn't remember where I'd seen this whether it was the App Store review guidelines or something else, it happened to be something else.

Comment: retainCount is useless don't call it.  retainCount can never return zero, for example.

Comment: Important: Xcode 5.1 no longer supports building OS X apps that use garbage collection; -->I'm using xcode 5.1 and I still use non-ARC to submit to appstore. it's fine. What's garbage collection?  I'm using non-ARC, because I develop this app for about 3 years. There're some 3rd party lib is not ARC, so I didn't change to ARC. If I change it to ARC, this kind of "message sent to deallocated instance" will be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- don't use `retainCount`.  It can never return 0, for example.
- the problem is that your delegate is being deallocated before the view controller is done mucking with it.   You *could* fix that by setting the delegate to `nil` in `dealloc`, but that may likely not be correct either in that it indicates that your view controller will live longer than the thing that it delegates behavioral decisions too.
- your `dealloc` method is wrong;  in non-ARC, you must call `[super dealloc];`
- you should use ARC

Comment: Thank,bbum. Your answer fixed my another problem. But, I'm not sure if it's the problem of delegate to nil for this problem (In fact, I just tried, but it still crash.), because it crashes just during the OrderViewController appear(not disappear.). OrderViewController should be active. And I press the textfield in OrderViewController, then it crash. And OrderViewController is not the delegate view for other View. It's only the delegate of textfield inside OrderTableView.   Can change code to ARC solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First check to make sure you aren't calling dealloc directly on it.

Then try running the Xcode Analyzer as it might find the problem for you.

Then try to enable an [Exception Breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) and see if it stops somewhere useful.

If those don't work try implementing the `-retain` and `-release` methods on the OrderTableViewController and then place breakpoints in each of them. You can then track who is retaining and releasing it and you should be able to find who is overreleasing it.

```
- (id)retain
{
    return [super retain];
}

-(oneway void)release
{
    [super release];
}
```

Comment: Easier to just turn on `track reference counts` in the Allocations Instrument and then use that to inspect retain/releases.   Breakpoints on overridden `retain`/`release` works, but is really tedious comparatively.

Comment: Ya, that is a great point. That is another very valid option. I thought about mentioning instruments as well. However, I like the retain release breakpoint method in some cases because it is a more familiar way to be able to look through the call stack and check the values of variables. Also, I think it gives an example of a way to think about debugging creatively without solving the problem with an existing tool.

Comment: Yup; hence the up vote. :)  Fun exercise;  use the introspection classes to be able to automatically dump the backtrace in those methods.   I have oft used exactly this technique to track down difficult to find memory issues in code that is not easily analyzed via Instruments.   If you implement a subclass of the misbehaving class and only instantiate it once or twice, it greatly reduces the logging noise.   For super tricky bonus points, you can peak at the thread/stack to not print backtraces that you know are not at issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should nil the delegate. That is, `uname.delegate = nil` in dealloc.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely the problem is you're releasing your viewController before the Navigation Controller has a chance to claim ownership. There are two ways around this:

- release your controller after pushing it to the Nav Controller
- autorelease your controller before pushing it. If you do this, the active NSAutoreleasePool (which you don't need to worry about) will take care of releasing your controller at a later time.

`[orderViewController autorelease];`

Comment: That is some nice code, why have you done it though??? -1 as there is zero explanation to it if you provide an explanation in your answer not comments I will remove my -1

Comment: As promised I have removed my -1

Comment: pushViewController:.. retains the controller.